# Getting info Silverlight controls using something similar to UI automation or other tech

Tags: c#-2.0

This is the first time I am asking a question. Can anyone please help me how to access Silverlight controls informations, similarly we used to get for WinForms applications using UI automation. Is there any way like UI automation from which I can get info about Silverlight applications? I have just basic knowledge about Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be looking at [Automation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationproperties%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

> Provides support for getting or setting the value of instance-level values of automation properties. These property values are set as attached properties (typically in XAML) and supplement or override automation property values from a control's [AutomationPeer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.automationpeer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

These require setting up in the Silverlight application.

Comment: thanks chrisF.....can automation properties and automation peer classes help me to get info about silver light controls,i have to write an application similar to silver light spy

Comment: @mmbiradar - Yes - but I'm not sure what you get out by default. I've only just started looking at them seriously myself. I've known they existed, but haven't had to use them yet.